# Rspec testing (can't tell whether a certain line of code is getting executed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I tried testing this method in rspec:

```
def resend_if_failed
  ResendWorker.new(self).resend_message
end
```

How do I test that `ResendWorker.new(self).resend_message` gets executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
worker = double
allow(ResendWorker).to receive(:new).and_return(worker)
expect(worker).to receive(:resend_message)

instance.resend_if_failed
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the instance in your spec, you can just do :

```
expect(instance).to receive(:resend_if_failed)
instance.resend_if_failed
```

Obviously I guess `resend_if_failed` is triggered by another method.

Then if necessary, test `resend_if_failed` behaviour in isolation.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I know how to get the method called but I want to check if `resend_message` is getting called on the new instance of `ResendWorker` in my test suite.